# Runescape.com auto redirect

Tags: windows-7

When I visit runescape.com I get auto redirected runescape wikia. (last time it redirected to microsoft.com)

I checked/tried

- cleaning with Malwarebytes
- Host file is empty
- Google Dns/Open Dns/ Automatic dns
- tracert shows good endpoint (if i go to that IP it lands at the runescape site)

I also thought this maybe something for gaming.stack but thats for game related.

Where could I fix this? Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: `ipconfig /flsuhdns`?

Comment: @techie007 didn't worked. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache.
Do a tracert several times to the domain and compare from the IP the browser takes you too.

Comment: Cleared the cache. If I take the Last IP from the trace it ends at runescape. (as it should). Thanks for replying. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use ad block extensions because it might be possible that there may be hidden scripts (used by ads) that redirects you. Also find if there are any tool bars are installed.

Comment: a good idea, but didn't help. Thanks